# newAPIHadoopFile in PySpark is not lazy

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter

I am trying to use a Hadoop FileInputFormat to read something in PySpark. I am using Jupyter with a PySpark-Kernel for this, but the error also happens when using the pyspark shell directly.

I am trying to read some file with a custom input format like this:

```
data = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://somewhere/*.foo", "com.example.FooInputFormat", "com.example.FooKeyClass", "com.example.FooValueClass")
```

Submitting just this bit of code should, to my understanding, not do anything because in Spark everything is lazy, so I expect to get no output whatsoever.

However, this is materialized immediately and Spark tries to run a `take()` on it. Is `newAPIHadoopFile` not lazy with PySpark? How do I achieve it being lazily read?

Comment: It seems that it is indeed lazy, but PySpark tries to take one value from it.

Comment: This is used  to build internal Java RDD. Is it a huge problem?

Comment: No, it is not. Never mind :) It just fetches the very first record so it doesn't take too long.